# (Done) Reopen: Handling requests that aren't for my department

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

As written [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120170/should-i-service-requests-at-work-that-are-not-my-departments-responsibility) wasn't on topic for TWP as it was more of a nebulous "should I...?" but I've done an edit and attempted to reframe it in a way that would be answerable here and I think the new version is answerable and should be reopened.

Comment: "*Is it appropriate for me to service requests that are within my capability but not my department's remit?*" Impossible for us to answer, OP should ask his manager that. The second question is answerable, but haven't we covered it before?

Answer (score 2):

This post is currently open again, after the edits you did.

I feel it's more answerable now, although I agree with Lilienthal that the second question is the one that has more answer material than the other... perhaps the post could still use one last edit to completely make it on-topic.